# The bot for VK answers in a private messages, and not in a conversation

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, chatbot, vk

I am creating a reference bot for chatting in VK in Python using the Callback Api. The bot works correctly if you write to the group messages. However, if you write to a conversation (to which the bot is added), it replies to private messages. All rights to read, etc. issued. As I understand it (studying information on the internet), I use `user_id`, not `chat_id`. But I didn't understand how to fix it correctly (

p.s. It is advisable that the bot write both in private messages and in a conversation, depending on where they ask.

p.p.s perhaps the question seems ridiculous, but I just started to study this area, and I did not find the answer on the net :-)

The bot itself:

```
import vk
import random
import messageHandler

@ app.route ('/', methods = ['POST'])
def processing ():
    data = json.loads (request.data)
    if 'type' not in data.keys ():
        return 'not vk'
    if data ['type'] == 'confirmation':
        return confirmation_token
    elif data ['type'] == 'message_new':
        messageHandler.create_answer (data ['object'] ['message'], token)
        return 'ok'
```

"Responder":

```
import importlib
from command_system import command_list

def load_modules ():
   # path from the working directory, it can be changed in the application settings
   files = os.listdir ("mysite / commands")
   modules = filter (lambda x: x.endswith ('. py'), files)
   for m in modules:
       importlib.import_module ("commands." + m [0: -3])

def get_answer (body):
    # Default message if unrecognizable
    message = "Sorry, I don't understand you. Write '/ help' to see my commands."
    attachment = ''
    for c in command_list:
        if body in c.keys:
            message, attachment = c.process ()
    return message, attachment

def create_answer (data, token):
   load_modules ()
   user_id = data ['from_id']
   message, attachment = get_answer (data ['text']. lower ())
   vkapi.send_message (user_id, token, message, attachment)
```

*I don't speak English well, so I apologize for the crooked translation)*

Answer (score 0):

Use Peer_id, instead of from_id.  (data->object->peer_id)
(i used php, but i had a similar problem. this is the solution)
probably something like this:

```
def create_answer (data, token):
   load_modules ()
   user_id = data ['peer_id'] # id source edited
   message, attachment = get_answer (data ['text']. lower ())
   vkapi.send_message (user_id, token, message, attachment)
```

**from_id** - person who sent the message

**peer_id** - in which dealogue message was received. (for groups it looks like 20000005)
So, you will send the message to conversation (does not matter is this PM or conversation with a lot of people)

Comment: Please apply proper text/code formattings to your answer.